# CMake does not include path to link libraries when compiling

Tags: c++, build, cmake, compiler-errors

So my directory structure is like

```
/
-- CMakeLists.txt

-- bencode/
---- bType.hpp
---- bType.cpp
---- Decoder.hpp
---- Decoder.cpp
---- CMakeLists.txt

-- torrent/
---- main.cpp
---- Torrent.hpp
---- Torrent.cpp
---- Tracker.hpp
---- Tracker.cpp
---- CMakeLists.txt
```

The root CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Torrent VERSION 1.0.0)
add_subdirectory(bencode)
add_subdirectory(torrent)
```

The bencode/CMakeLists.txt is

```
add_library(
    Decoder
    Decoder.hpp
    Decoder.cpp
)
add_library(
    bType
    bType.hpp
    bType.cpp
)
target_include_directories(bType PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE/_DIR}")
target_include_directories(Decoder PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

The torrent/CMakeLists.txt is

```
add_library(
    Torrent
    Torrent.hpp
    Torrent.cpp
)
add_library(
    Tracker
    Tracker.hpp
    Tracker.cpp
)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
    main PRIVATE
    Torrent Tracker
    Decoder bType
)
```

Whenever I build, the `Torrent.cpp` compilation fails, as it includes `Decoder.hpp` which is not in the same directory, and the build command does not include the path during compilation

```
[build] ../torrent/Torrent.cpp:5:10: fatal error: Decoder.hpp: No such file or directory
[build]  #include <Decoder.hpp>
[build]           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] comp
```

There should have been a `-I` flag while compiling but there isn't.

Help me figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the location of `Decoder.hpp` as a *public* include directory of `Decoder`, and use `target_link_libraries` to link `Torrent` to `Decoder`, CMake will pick up that you need `Torrent` to search the proper locations to find `Docoder`'s headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have linked all of the library targets to `main`, but if there is a *dependency* between the `Torrent` library and the `Decoder` library, you should **link** `Decoder` to `Torrent` also. To propagate the include directories of the `Decoder` library to the `Torrent` library, use the `PUBLIC` argument in the `target_include_directories()` call instead.

**bencode/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(
    Decoder
    Decoder.hpp
    Decoder.cpp
)
add_library(
    bType
    bType.hpp
    bType.cpp
)
target_include_directories(bType PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
# Use PUBLIC here to propagate the include directories to consumers.
target_include_directories(Decoder PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

**torrent/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(
    Torrent
    Torrent.hpp
    Torrent.cpp
)
add_library(
    Tracker
    Tracker.hpp
    Tracker.cpp
)
add_executable(main main.cpp)

# Link Decoder to Torrent here, because Torrent depends on Decoder.
target_link_libraries(Torrent PUBLIC Decoder)

# Link the other libraries to main, Decoder will be brought along with Torrent.
target_link_libraries(
    main PRIVATE
    Torrent 
    Tracker
    bType
)
```